# Why is $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\psi(x)}{x}=1$ equivalent to the prime number theorem?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Statement) it is said that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\psi(x)}{x}=1$$ is equivalent to the prime number theorem ($\psi$ is the second Chebyshev function). Does anybody know some references for this?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936775/prime-number-theorem-lemma-prove-that-psix-sim-pix-logx?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sections 4.1-4.4 in Apostol's *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*, and in particular Theorem 4.4 on page 79, is a good source for this:

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Apply the [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts).

With $\Lambda(n) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}\ln p & \text{if } n= p^k \\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$, $\ \psi(x) = \sum_{n \le x} \Lambda(n)$. Assuming we proved $\psi(x) = \mathcal{O}(x)$ :

$$\begin{eqnarray}\pi(x) &=& \sum_{p \le x} 1 \\
&=& \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{x})+\sum_{n \le x} \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\ln n} \\
&=& \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{x})+\frac{\psi(x)}{\ln x} + \sum_{n < x} \psi(n)(\frac{1}{\ln n}-\frac{1}{\ln (n+1)})\\
 &=&\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{x})+ \frac{\psi(x)}{\ln x} +  \sum_{n < x} \psi(n)\frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}{\ln n \ \ln(n+1)} \\
&=& \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{x})+\frac{\psi(x)}{\ln x} + \mathcal{O}( \sum_{2 \le n < x}\frac{1}{(\ln n)^2}) \\
&=& \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{x})+\frac{\psi(x)}{\ln x} + \mathcal{O}(\frac{x}{(\ln x)^2}) \end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: How did you get the second equality $O(\sqrt{x})+\sum_{n\le x} \Lambda (n)/\ln n$ ?